Kivy MD: Multiple Columns Menu Display Issue
I'm encountering an issue with my Kivy MD application where the navigation menu is displayed in three columns instead of a single column layout (The menu is multiplied by 3). Here's an overview of my app:
#app.py

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from login import LoginScreen
from main import MainScreen
from users import UsersScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("login.kv")
Builder.load_file("main.kv")
Builder.load_file("users.kv")

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        self.sm.add_widget(UsersScreen(name='users'))
        return self.sm

    def switch_to_main(self):
        self.sm.current = 'main'

    def toggle_nav_drawer(self):
        if self.sm.current == 'main':
            screen = self.sm.get_screen('main')
        elif self.sm.current == 'users':
            screen = self.sm.get_screen('users')
        else:
            return
        
        nav_drawer = screen.ids.nav_drawer
        nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()

#login.py

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Builder.load_file("login.kv")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def verify_credentials(self):
        username = self.ids.username.text
        password = self.ids.password.text

        if username == "admin" and password == "admin":
            app = MDApp.get_running_app()
            app.switch_to_main()
        else:
            print("Invalid credentials")

#main.py:

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from users import UsersScreen

Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreenContent(Screen):
    pass

#main.kv:

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "main"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Users"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "users"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Settings"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "About"

<MainScreen>:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            MainScreenContent:
                name: "main"
            UsersScreen:
                name: "users"
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer

<MainScreenContent>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Main Screen - PPP"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.get_running_app().toggle_nav_drawer()]]
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Label:
            text: "Welcome to the Main Screen!"
            font_size: 30
            bold: True
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            color: "000000"  # Setează culoarea textului la negru



<UsersScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "User Page - APP"  # Titlul personalizat
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.get_running_app().toggle_nav_drawer()]]
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            size_hint: 1, 0.9

#users.py:

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp

Builder.load_file('users.kv')

class UsersScreen(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            column_data=[
                ("Column 1", dp(20)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(50), self.sort_on_col_3),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
                ("Column 6", dp(30)),
                ("Column 7", dp(30), self.sort_on_col_2),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (
                    "1",
                    ("alert", [255 / 256, 165 / 256, 0, 1], "No Signal"),
                    "Astrid: NE shared managed",
                    "Medium",
                    "Triaged",
                    "0:33",
                    "Chase Nguyen",
                ),
                (
                    "2",
                    ("alert-circle", [1, 0, 0, 1], "Offline"),
                    "Cosmo: prod shared ares",
                    "Huge",
                    "Triaged",
                    "0:39",
                    "Brie Furman",
                ),
                (
                    "3",
                    (
                        "checkbox-marked-circle",
                        [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                        "Online",
                    ),
                    "Phoenix: prod shared lyra-lists",
                    "Minor",
                    "Not Triaged",
                    "3:12",
                    "Jeremy lake",
                ),
                (
                    "4",
                    (
                        "checkbox-marked-circle",
                        [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                        "Online",
                    ),
                    "Sirius: NW prod shared locations",
                    "Negligible",
                    "Triaged",
                    "13:18",
                    "Angelica Howards",
                ),
                (
                    "5",
                    (
                        "checkbox-marked-circle",
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ZLv9RvPm.png)                        [39 / 256, 174 / 256, 96 / 256, 1],
                        "Online",
                    ),
                    "Sirius: prod independent account",
                    "Negligible",
                    "Triaged",
                    "22:06",
                    "Diane Okuma",
                ),
            ],
        )
        layout.add_widget(data_tables)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def sort_on_col_3(self, data):
        return zip(
            *sorted(
                enumerate(data),
                key=lambda l: l[1][3]
            )
        )

    def sort_on_col_2(self, data):
        return zip(
            *sorted(
                enumerate(data),
                key=lambda l: l[1][-1]
            )
        )


What could be causing the navigation drawer to display menu items in multiple columns instead of a single column layout when I consolidate the MainApp class in app.py? How can I ensure it displays correctly?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you
